# Can't login after a PATH modification

Tags: release-loki, boot

I'm sorry to bother you, but I think I've just made a huge mistake. I was trying to install TexLive on my Elementary OS distro. I was following this guide (italian, unfortunately): [link](http://profs.sci.univr.it/~gregorio/texlive-YEAR-ubuntu.pdf)

In the chapter 7, there was this sequence of commands

$ echo 'export PATH=/opt/texbin:${PATH}' > texlive.sh 
$ sudo cp texlive.sh /etc/profile.d/ 
$ sudo mkdir -p /opt 
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-linux /opt/texbin

I'm not so sure, but I think that I've wrongly written also another command: $ sudo rm /opt/texbin (in the guide it's reported some lines later, talking about updating TexLive), and then, as it's writtend, I logged out. 
But after this, I'm stucked in the login: when I enter my username and password, it gets a black screen for a moment and then it come back to login screen. 
I've tried to type CTL+ALT+F1, then after my username and password
, any command is not executed: it appears an error like "command 'sudo' is available in 'usr/bin/sudo'. The command can't be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.

Does anyone know how to fix this? :(

Answer (score 1):

Boot from a live USB or DVD.
Then mount the drive (instructions for this abound on the net).

Navigate to your user's home folder:

```
cd /home/<your username>
```

Look at the contents of your `.bashrc` file in your home folder.

Using `vi`, `nano`, `gedit` or similar, edit the line in `.bashrc` that defines the `PATH` variable, so that it contains:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Save that.
Unmount the drive.

This should allow you to resume normal function after rebooting.